How to test a method call with keyword arguments not including a particular keyword
I have the following method:
def clone(branch: nil, depth: nil)
  ...
end

For a particular test case, I want to test that the method is called without the branch argument. In Ruby 2.x the following test case was working properly:
it 'clones the created repository without a branch' do
  expect(repository).to receive(:clone).with(hash_excluding(:branch))
  method_call
end

However in Ruby 3.x this stopped working because:
#<InstanceDouble(Repository) (anonymous)> received :clone with unexpected arguments
  expected: (hash_not_including(:branch=>"anything"))
       got: (no args)

Is there any way to test this without having to change the method to receive an Options Hash instead of keyword arguments? I searched around the net but the closest thing I could find was someone wishing for a keywords_including and keywords_not_including matcher but no concrete answer.
Before opening an issue on RSpec's Github repo, is there already a way to perform this test?

Note: For this test I do not want to explicitly define any other parameters, i.e. I would not want to do this:
expect(repository).to receive(:clone).with(depth: anything)

I explicitly want to test for the absence of the branch parameter.

I tried turning the expectation around like this:
expect(repository).not_to receive(:clone).with(branch: anything)

And this works as long as the method is called only with the branch parameter, for example:
clone(branch: 'FETCH_HEAD')

This makes the test fail as expected, however, as soon as another parameter is added:
clone(branch: 'FETCH_HEAD', depth: 1)

The test passes even though the call includes the branch parameter.

I found an answer here.
A possible way to do this is:
expect(repository).to receive(:clone) do |**kwargs|
  expect(kwargs).not_to include(:branch)
end

Admittedly not as neat as a single matcher but it get the job done.
